# undefined method `with_scope' when trying to create new user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I encounter a problem when trying to create a new user .
When I click on create,
undefined method `with_scope' for #
this shows up.

```
  @user.timezonepref = User.find(@user.parent_id).timezonepref

  if @user.save


    The error console shows that the problem is in the line 'if @user.save'
```

I don't know why and when I grep for 'with_scope' under the whole folder , I don't see such function exists in any file.
And I also tried to drop, and re-create the whole database. But it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

The with_scope is an ActiveRecord method. You will not find it in your source code. Go to Rails console and reproduce the problem. You can also do `@user.errors.full_messsages` to check for error messages.